timeout with netcat connection and established connection with netstat
I would like to check if there is a open port in remote machine, so I always use:
nc -zv 10.4.2.4 2760
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: TIMEOUT.

Like you see it gives me timeout. But when I use netstat I see an established connection.
netstat -an | grep -i 2760
tcp        0      0 10.0.218.126:54568      10.4.2.8:2760           ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.218.126:50700      10.4.2.4:2760           ESTABLISHED

I am almost sure that the port is opened but the behaviour of netcat command confused me.
Could you explain these? Thanks
